Facing problem while creating build of electron js project
i found this error in my terminal while i'm creating build
• electron-builder  version=24.13.3 os=10.0.22631
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=keytar@7.9.0, sqlite3@5.1.6 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • install prebuilt binary  name=keytar version=7.9.0 platform=win32 arch=x64 napi=
• packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=26.6.10 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z size=5.6 MB parts=1
  • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z duration=7.603s
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 2
                    out=
    7-Zip (a) 21.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2021-12-26

    Scanning the drive for archives:
    1 file, 5635384 bytes (5504 KiB)


Open your vs code editor Run as administrator in project folder
